# Data synchronization per user api

Tags: php, api, rest, symfony, offline

I expose de problem :

I have api for a offline client application.

i have for exemple many end-points :

- endpoint1 : GET /api/foo (return resources based on connected user and business logic)
- endpoint2 : GET /api/bar (return resources based on connected user and business logic)
- endpoint3 : GET /api/fou (return resources based on connected user and business logic)

We want to call this url only where there are resources changes.

- Solution 1 : Add Etag for each end-point and client call the url with `if-none-match: Etag`

With an environment where the internet is very weak make X (number of end-point) requests seems not good.

- Solution 2 :  the client call url /api/resourceVersion with connected user for exemple and we return

```
{
  endpoint1: 'HASH1' or (true | false),
  endpoint2: 'HASH2' or (true | false),
  endpoint3: 'HASH3' or (true | false),
}
```

true there are change, false no change.

If true the client call the specific endpoint to update his local data

The problem of this solution is that we can't call each end-point to check if ressource changes with a Etag or other when client call api/resourceVersion.

My question : is there a powerful solution for the end-point /api/resourceVersion ?

Comment: This is just a hint, but instead of "polling for results" you may think of rather "pushing" update-infos to the client. (for example websockets)

Comment: We test the pushing for other feature and we see that is not safe, some time client receive  nothing due to weakly internet

Comment: What comes in my mind is that you have an extra "bookkeeping-table" in your db where there is a datetime column for each endpoint, on the server-side you update this accordingly and on the client side you call this to compare with last client saved dates for each endpoint and load accordingly.